# Removed current running linux-image

Tags: 12.04, boot, apt

I had the problem of a full /boot. So i decided to remove old linux-images. However in the process I accidentally removed the current in-use image. Which would be linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic on Ubuntu 12.04.

Trying a apt-get -f install results in:

```
dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.54.64); however:
Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.60.71.
linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.54.64); however:
Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.60.71.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.                                                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:linux-server
```

However I didn't apt-get remove linux-image-server because I'm not sure what will happen.

What would be a way to make a package of the current running image so the machine can be rebooted again?

Comment: so why dont you do `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0` if you just want to install your linux-image back

Comment: @user273096 Please *don't* add "(Solved)" to the question title. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7413/attaching-solved-to-title-of-questions-with-accepted-answers

Comment: @user273096 Also please *don't* edit you question to add your solution. Add your answer as an answer below and accept it. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3004/how-do-i-answer-my-own-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### OP posted

After removing `linux-image-server` with `apt-get remove`, I managed to fix it with a

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Since I removed the current running linux-image, I figured I could reinstall them with `apt-get`.